# Query Error: Date Parsing Issue in Redis Search

Tags: typescript, date, parsing, error-handling, redis

I've run into an issue while querying dates, and I could use some input. The query I've constructed looks properly structured to me:
(((@employeeId:{ 3 })) | ((@tags:{ ParticipantEmployeeId:3 }))) (@tags:{StartDate_unixms:[1577923200000 +inf]})

However, I keep encountering this error:

ReplyError: Syntax error at offset 89 near StartDate_unixms
at parseError (C:\Woolworths\Digitial Team Management\node_modules\redis-parser\lib\parser.js:179:12)
at parseType (C:\Woolworths\Digitial Team Management\node_modules\redis-parser\lib\parser.js:302:14)

I suspect the issue might be related to how I'm storing dates in the database. Currently, they're stored as strings within an array, and I think that might be causing the problem. Despite my best efforts in parsing, it seems Redis is interpreting the date as a string in the range query.

If anyone has any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance for your help! (screenshot below so you understand how the date is stored)[db tags array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVq9B.png)

Constructed a query to search for dates using Redis syntax.
Ensured the query structure seems correct.
Confirmed that the dates are stored as strings in the database.
Anticipating that the issue might be related to how Redis handles string representations of dates in range queries.